# Bitbucket.org & Git Extensions

Tags: git, bitbucket

First, I'd like to say I'm NOT a developer.  I use Git Extensions and Bitbucket to create War Files and APK files for applications, our development team builds.

Here is my issue.  In Git Extensions, who is connected to Bitbucket.org for the repository, I like to create tags on various branches.

I was able to create a tag for a few days, then all of a sudden my authentication is failing.  Keep in mind, that I'm pulling from Bitbucket.org on a daily basis, and have no authentication problems except when I create and push a tag.

It is not a password mistype or anything of the kind.  Has anyone heard of this and know how to fix it?

I have the same issue in Git Extensions in a different repository however, the problem is not tagging.  It's pushing.

I have changed my password on Bitbucket.org.  This did not solve anything.  I have used a different installation of Git Extensions, and same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited to BitBucket support

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but instead of https I would try using ssh. (I assume you use https because you said you need to type your credentials on pull.) Here is a guide for setting it up: [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git)

Comment: SSH can require credentials with each remote action as well, if you haven't cached your key into any sort of SSH agent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a permission problem.  Again as stated, I'm not a developer, thus, I only had read access.  Once, I was given Write access, the problem was solved.